# animation of an UIImageView run only once

Tags: animation, uiimageview

I am writing a game. After attacker kills a soldier, a dropping UIImageView saying experience+1 will show.

Now, the animation shows correctly when I kills 1st soldier, but **not show** when killing 2nd soldier and later.

animation codes, method name is showGainXPAnimationAfterKillSoldier.

```
    imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.hidden = FALSE;
    [imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.layer removeAllAnimations];
    imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.frame = CGRectMake(140, 220, 53, 19);
    // a loop to show animation.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    //imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 53, 19);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-112, 215);
    imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.transform = transform;
    //imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

call animation codes,

```
    if (killedSoldierCount>0) {
    // add imgview to show gained XP.
    if (imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier) {
        MWLog(@"remove it!");
        [imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.layer removeAllAnimations];
        [imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier removeFromSuperview];

    }
    imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.frame = CGRectMake(140, 220, 53, 19);
    imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.hidden = TRUE;
    //imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier.alpha = 1.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:imgGainXPAfterKillSoldier];

    switch (killedSoldierCount) {
        case 1:
            // show add experience animation after kill soldier.
            MWLog(@"kill a soldier, show XP+1 animation.");
            [self showGainXPAnimationAfterKillSoldier:1];
            break;
```

what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now the problem is fixed. every time I want to animate, I create a new UIImageView to do that. without using the UIImageView defined in xib file repeatly.